# Rails: creating dynamic filter from dynamic dropdown list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic-linking

I'm new to Rails and need a help.
I have a category dropdown list on navbar in Index page which shows a list of menu items. The dropdown is dynamically generated from category table but I don't know how to dynamically create a link from dynamically generated category in order to filter the items by the selected category.

The expected query when clicking category item in the dropdown menu would be something like this:

select * from menus where menus.category_id = category.id

category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :menus
end
```

menu.rb

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

menus_controller.rb

```
def index
    @brand = Brand.find(params[:brand_id])
    @category = @brand.categories
    @menu = Menu.where(brand_id: params[:brand_id]).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

views/menus/index.html.haml

```
  %ul.dropdown-menu
    - @category.each do |category|
      %li
        %a= link_to category.name
```

I managed to generate categories from database but don't know where to go from here. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this. http://pullmonkey.com/2012/08/11/dynamic-select-boxes-ruby-on-rails-3/ worked like a charm.

**You just need something like this**

```
collection_select(nil, :genre_id,  @genres,  :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Genre"}, {:id => 'genres_select'})
```

**and do not need to add**

```
@category.each do |category|
```